# Issue when using a loop for accordion with JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a problem with this code:

```
for(var element in partsListById)
{
    $('.title#'+partsListById[element]).on('click touch', function(e){
        $('.part#'+partsListById[element]).slideToggle();
    });
}
```

the partsListById array contains a string list of the name of the objects I want to target.

I don't understand why the code above doesn't work and this one works:

```
$('.title#sensor').on('click touch', function(e){
    $('.part#sensor').slideToggle();
});
```

Where is my mistake?

I'm realy new in JS.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: It is really bad to have multiple elements on the page with the same id.

Comment: `for(const element in partsListById)`

Comment: Seems like you really do not need the loop. Something like the following would probably work. `$('.title').on('click touch', function(e){
        $('.part#'+this.id).slideToggle();
    });`

Comment: post the array what it contains , also you html code

Comment: @iota thank you, it wored!

Comment: @espascarello thank you for your advice!

Comment: @Matio No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `let` or `const` so that the variable is local to the loop block.

```
for(const element in partsListById)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the loop is not executed, that is, the Value of "partsListById" is empty.
First Check the Value "partsListById"

```
console.log(partsListById);
```

if is null the loop is not executed.